# MAGMI import stops at the first line

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

Im using the latest version of magmi on my installation (magento 1.9.3.4)

When I run a import to update a single attribute it stops on 1.

It also says 'Initialized attribute_set_infos!'

Has anyone had the same problem or does anyone have any ideas. Thanks[image]

[image]

[image]

The file im tyring to import is simply 2 products to test. With headers 'sku' and 'order_code' (.csv file with UTF-8 formatting.)

sku,order_code
testproduct,TEST
9015-2160,TU05122

I know this is a Magmi issue and not exactly Magento but I always get good support from this community and I have used the magmi tag. Thanks again

Comment: can you include the first two lines of the csv data you are trying to import in your question.

Comment: Ive added some more info, let me know if there is anything more yo need. Thank you

Comment: your csv enclosure is set to quotes but your data is not qouted.

Comment: Make sure CSV is saved as UTF8 w/o BOM.

Comment: I have tried with and without quotes, and without BOM but still no luck. Any other ideas? Thank you

Comment: The problem seems to be only with importing in values that are for multi select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/issues/436

My server runing php7, I change global -> Reporting step in %: to 1, it works.